# Nested if statements, any possible way of cleaning?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have checked a few other questions but they don't really give me the answer I expect..

My code is a like this..

```
private function handle()
{
    if()
    {
        if(!condition)
        {
            if(!condition)
            {
                if(!condition)
                {
                    if(!condition))
                    {
                        if(!condition)
                        {
                            if(!condition)
                            {
                                if(!condition)
                                {
                                    if(!condition)
                                    {
                                        if(!condition)
                                        {
                                            code
                                        }

                                        return;
                                    }

                                    return;
                                }

                                return;
                            }

                            return;
                        }

                        return;
                    }

                    return;
                }

                return;
            }


            return;
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

In my opinion it is readable but messy, sadly I haven't found really a way of making it look 'pretty'. Any ideas?

EDIT: Each return is different.
EDIT2: Gave an answer of my own, thanks everybody!

Comment: If the only place where actual code exists is in the inner-most scope, you can flatten the structure into something like `if(first_precondition_failed) { return error_1; } if(second_precondition_failed) { return error_2; } ... if(last_precondition_failed) { return error_x; } /* code */  `.

Comment: You just have recursive `if` with no statement block until the part `code` is reached, I'd suggest the same as [Rajat Singhal](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1114536/rajat-singhal) suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Conditions can be merged by a `&&` operator..It works form left to right, which means, as soon as the any one starting from left fails, it stops evaluating the condition..

```
if($a) {

    if($b) {
    }

}
```

can be replaced by

```
if($a && $b) {
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not pointing it out, but each one returns a different error.

Comment: @Manuel, if they *return* the error, then your code will also be more readable with sequential, non-nested ifs: `if ( ! $a) return $error1;` (and so on and so forth). Later ifs will only be evaluated if former ifs did not throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable check, or combine the conditions into fewer IF statements.

Variable check like so:

```
$execute = TRUE;
// Opposite of what you want, e.g. if you want $a only to be TRUE, do $a !== TRUE
if (condition) {
  $execute = FALSE;
}

...
// If all the conditions were met, then everything is OK
if($execute === TRUE) {
  // code
}else {
  // return
}
```

Edit:
Variable check can be preferably to combining IF statements if you want more control on what returns, e.g. something specific happens if a certain condition fails, which combining conditions can not always allow for.

Answer (score 0):

Like already posted use

```
if(condition1&&condition2){}
```

or if this will not work, you can also use function which stops as soon as a condition is true

```
function some(){
if(!conditon 1){return 0;}
if(condition 2) {return 1;}
}
```

this provides more power as second if works only if first doesn't satisfy. 
You must choose based on your requirements. Sometimes though nested loops are unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it out and have found a nice way of doing it, basically I'll make a method for each basic condition, and I'll call them in an if statement with the bitwise AND operator (&), which don't short-circuit.

```
/**
 * nonsql_condition - It means it doesn't check with the database
 *
 * sql_condition - It means it does check with the database.
 */
if(!$this->nonsql_condition() & !$this->nonsql_condition() & !$this->nonsql_condition() & !$this->nonsql_condition())
{
    if(!$this->sql_condition())
    {
       return error;
    }

    if(!$this->sql_condition())
    {
       return error;
    }

    code;
}
```

This allows me to use fewer lines of code in my method, plus also not doing unnecessary queries to my database.